# JavaScript / jQuery - how to process form with js and then submit it without ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-loop

I am writing a website using Python / Django, and am currently doing server-side geocoding through the geopy module.  I would like to implement a progressive enhancement of doing the geocoding via Javascript (to make sure I don't hit Google's daily limit of geocode requests / user), and then pass the results of the Javascript geocoding to the server for further processing.

What I am currently doing is using javascript and the Google geocoding API to get the (lat, lon) coordinates and add them as hidden inputs into my form.  However, I am not sure how to submit this form with the (lat, lon) without running into an infinite loop.  I would rather stay away from sending this via Ajax because for this particular page 99.9% of the page needs to be refreshed, and I would like to keep the design as simple as possible, so Ajax would be overkill.

I played around with putting the event.preventDefault() into an if statement testing for existence of the hidden lat/lon variables, but could not get it to work.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!  Vasiliy

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var g = new GoogleGeocode();  

//bind event handler
$('#address_form').bind('submit', function(event){

    //get address from form
    var address = $('#id_address').val();

    event.preventDefault();

    //get lat/lon
    g.geocode(address, function(data) {  
        if(data != null) {  
            alert(data.longitude + " " + data.latitude);  
            //insert lat and lon into the form
            $('<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="' + data.latitude + '"/>').appendTo('form');
            $('<input type="hidden" id="lon" name="lon" value="' + data.longitude + '"/>').appendTo('form');
        } else {  
            alert('ERROR! Unable to geocode address');  
        }
    });  
});
});
```

Comment: I don't get your question. Why would you run into an infinte loop? Do you just need to test for the existence of lat and lon?

Comment: I solved it thanks to ShankarSangoli's comment of unbinding the submit.  But, just curious why the other way didn't work...before, I tried to put the event.preventDefault into an if statement testing if the lat/lon hidden fields existed.  However, that didn't work, and I'm not sure why.  I even did a simple test,

if 1>0 {
    event.preventDefault();
}

and this did not trigger the preventDefault.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `unbind` the form `submit` event handler once you are sure you have to submit the form. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var g = new GoogleGeocode();  

//bind event handler
$('#address_form').bind('submit', function(event){

    //get address from form
    var address = $('#id_address').val();

    event.preventDefault();

    //get lat/lon
    g.geocode(address, function(data) {  
        if(data != null) {  
            alert(data.longitude + " " + data.latitude);  
            //insert lat and lon into the form
            $('<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="' + data.latitude + '"/>').appendTo('form');
            $('<input type="hidden" id="lon" name="lon" value="' + data.longitude + '"/>').appendTo('form');

             $('#address_form').unbind('submit').submit();

        } else {  
            alert('ERROR! Unable to geocode address');  
        }
    });  
});
```

});

Comment: ShankarSangoli - adding the unbind worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the `submit` handler, check whether you already geocoded, and, if so, `return`.  (not `false`).
If you return before doing anything, the browser will submit normally.

Alternatively, just unbind the handler after you geocode.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false at the end of the function

Comment: `preventDefault` should be preferred over that.

Comment: Returning false will prevent the submission, which is exactly what he doesn't want.